# Extract integers from string

Tags: java, android, string

In my app, I get a string. For example:

```
"1 \n2 4 \n18 \n 3 20 12 \n 4\n23"
```

I want to get all the integers from the string like

```
1,2,4,18,3,20,12,4,23.
```

I can't use `string.split`. There are only 2 characters except numbers (new line character and space in my string).

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why can't you use `String.split()` function?

Comment: Android don't have split in its java implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you only have integers (in range -2147483648 and 2147483647) in your text (and whitespaces) you can easily use `Scanner`

```
String input = "1 \n2 4 \n18 \n 3 20 12 \n 4\n23";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
while(sc.hasNextInt())
    System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
```

For numbers out of these range you can use `nextLong` or `nextBigInteger`. But if you are not interested in returning actual type and you are fine with having them as `String` you can simply use `next`.

Comment: Does `Scanner` exists in Android?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I didn't check but it is part of `java.util` so I don't see any reason not to include it to Android (also fact that OP accepted this answer makes me think that it it worked on Android).

Comment: @BuhakeSindi This documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Scanner.html claims that Scanner exists on Android.

Answer (score 2):

You can use REGEX with `\\d+`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "1 \n2 4 \n18 \n 3 20 12 \n 4\n23";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
1
2
4
18
3
20
12
4
23
```

Comment: @isht - Glad I could be of help :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringTokenizer to do it on Android.

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(yourString, "\\n");
```

Comment: `"\n"` will be treated as newline. `"\\n"` will identify the string literal `\n`.

Comment: I meant a new line only

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the Pattern / Matcher reply above...

If only you want to use split, this will work:

```
String str = "1 \n2 4 \n18 \n 3 20 12 \n 4\n23";
StringBuffer bfr = new StringBuffer();
for (String splitStr: str.split("[\\n\\s]+")){
    bfr.append("," + splitStr);
}
System.out.println(bfr.toString().substring(1));
}
```

or use tokenizer:

```
String str = "1 \n2 4 \n18 \n 3 20 12 \n 4\n23";
StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(str, "[\n ]+");
StringBuffer bfr = new StringBuffer();
while (strToken.hasMoreElements()){
    bfr.append("," + strToken.nextElement().toString());
}
System.out.println(bfr.toString().substring(1));
}
```